# Es posible acceder al siguiente JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, jsonobject

estoy intentando procesar la data brindada de: [Twitch Helix (API)](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/).

Utilize Javascript con: `JSON.stringify`:

```
{"data":
  [{
   "id":"user_id",
      "login":"user_login",
         "display_name":"user_ds",
           "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
              "description":"user_desc",
              "profile_image_url":"url",
              "offline_image_url":"url",
              "view_count":123
    },
    {
    "id":"user_id",
     "login":"user_login",
       "display_name":"user_ds",
          "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
           "description":"user_desc",
          "profile_image_url":"url",
           "offline_image_url":"url",
             "view_count":123
     }
  ]
}
```

Luego intente acceder mediante:

```
    var datos = JSON.stringify(json);
    console.log(datos.data);
```

Pero  el resultado fue: `datos.data undefined`. Intente otras maneras pero ya estoy confundido.

Tambien utilize PHP: json_decode() para ver exactamente como estaba estructurado.
Resultado:

```
  array (
    'data' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 'user_id',
        'login' => 'user_login',
        'display_name' => 'user_ds',
        'type' => '',
        'broadcaster_type' => 'partner',
        'description' => 'user_desc',
        'profile_image_url' => 'url',
        'offline_image_url' => 'url',
        'view_count' => 123,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 'user_id',
        'login' => 'user_login',
        'display_name' => 'user_ds',
        'type' => '',
        'broadcaster_type' => 'partner',
        'description' => 'user_desc',
        'profile_image_url' => 'url',
        'offline_image_url' => 'url',
        'view_count' => 123,
      ),
    ),
  )
```

¿Existe la posibilidad de acceder a cierto campo, ej: `user_login`?

De ser posible, para acceder a varios `user_login`
¿Como puedo hacerlo con `$.each()`?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente

Declaras dentro de una variable la data que intentas iterar, así

```
let datos = {"data":
  [{
   "id":"user_id",
      "login":"user_login",
         "display_name":"user_ds",
           "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
              "description":"user_desc",
              "profile_image_url":"url",
              "offline_image_url":"url",
              "view_count":123
    },
    {
    "id":"user_id",
     "login":"user_login",
       "display_name":"user_ds",
          "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
           "description":"user_desc",
          "profile_image_url":"url",
           "offline_image_url":"url",
             "view_count":123
     }
  ]
}
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, vas a iterar sobre esta misma estructura mediante un `forEach`, pero accediendo primero a la clave principal que contiene el resto de valores, que en este caso es: `data` quedando del modo siguiente

```
datos.data.forEach(function(key, value){
  console.log(key["view_count"])
})
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Accedo primero a la variable que lo contiene, que es `datos`
- Posterior accedo a la `key` principal que en este caso es data
- Para mostrar un `value` de una `key` específica exacta lo hago a través de `key["keyName"]` donde `key` es uno de los argumentos que le pasé a dicha función anónima dentro del `forEach`

Como resultado final obtengo

```
123
123
```

Donde como puedes ver al estar iterando dentro de los valores de `data` que es la key principal, al momento de yo colocarle la llave a la que quiero acceder me muestra todas las que coinciden por el nombre; en este caso es `["view_count"]`

Para sumar el valor que retorna la key `["view_count"]` quedaría de este modo

```
let res
datos.data.forEach(function(key, value){
  res = key["view_count"] += key["view_count"]
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio bastante! Cancele el JSON.stringify y le coloque directamente el JSON, siendo asi me entrego exactamente lo especificado.

Comment: Algo extra, y si necesito que esos [view_count] sean sumados en su totalidad? @element

Comment: mira la actualización @Juan

Comment: Gracias lo probare, lo que ahora me resulto algo "dificil". Explico breve: El json varia de si la persona transmite (envia datos) y si esta offline (envia null)... Como puedo verificar ej: Key1 =  ["user_login"] .. siendo user_login ej: Juan. ? Las condiciones van fuera del forEach?

Comment: considero que por esta pregunta hemos terminado, para seguir el orden de la plataforma; podrías abrir una pregunta nueva indicando la nueva situación a la que te enfrentas y continuar recibiendo apoyo @Juan

Comment: Hola element, he creado una pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240427/condici%c3%b3nes-para-resultados-de-un-foreach