# Condiciónes para resultados de un forEach

Tags: javascript, json, object

Al solucionar el acceso a un JSON mediante forEach ([Es posible acceder al siguiente JSON?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240386/es-posible-acceder-al-siguiente-json/240390?noredirect=1#comment447071_240390)).

Me surgieron las siguientes dudas:

¿Cómo puedo acceder a cada "each" para ingresarle condiciones if/else?

Es decir:

```
     var response = json; // json file or response

    response.data.forEach(function(key, value){

        console.log("Nombre: "+key["username"]+"."); 
       // response: Nombre: Juan. Nombre: Luis. Nombre: Micaela.

        })
```

Quiero tratar de hacer algo como:

```
         if(key["username"]==="Juan"){
                console.log(key["username"])
         // Nececito que sea: Juan. Y no todos los nombres.
            }else{
                  console.log("No username");
                }
```

Ahora bien, el JSON/Object (proviene de la Twitch Api Helix).
Si el "streamer" esta en vivo, twitch envia un object con data.
Si el "streamer" esta offline, twitch no envia ningun object.

Es decir: (api call para 3 usuarios - 2 on - 1 off)

```
   let datos = {"data":
[{
    "id":"user_id",
  "login":"user_login",
     "display_name":"user_ds",
       "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
          "description":"user_desc",
          "profile_image_url":"url",
          "offline_image_url":"url",
          "view_count":123
     },
     {
"id":"user_id",
 "login":"user_login",
   "display_name":"user_ds",
      "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
       "description":"user_desc",
      "profile_image_url":"url",
       "offline_image_url":"url",
         "view_count":123
      }
   ]
 }
```

¿ Existe la posibilidad de obtener esos datos segun el (key,value) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes los argumentos del [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) al revés, primero va value y luego key. Si quieres filtrar los valores, puedes aplicar [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let datos = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id":"user_id",
      "login":"user_login",
      "display_name":"user_ds",
      "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
      "description":"user_desc",
      "profile_image_url":"url",
      "offline_image_url":"url",
      "view_count":123
    },
    {
      "id":"user_id",
      "login":"user_login",
      "display_name":"user_ds",
      "type":"","broadcaster_type":"partner",
      "description":"user_desc",
      "profile_image_url":"url",
      "offline_image_url":"url",
      "view_count":123
    }
  ]
}

datos.data.filter(function(value) {
  return value.display_name === 'user_ds'; // Solo pasan los que tengan este display_name
}).forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log('Posición en el array: ' + key);
  console.log('Objeto: ', value);
  console.log('Propiedad "display_name": ' + value.display_name);
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Esto brindaria los datos del que pasa en el return? O solamente brinda el display_name?

Comment: Filter elimina los elementos del array para los que la función que le pasas devuelve `false`. En tu caso, `datos.data` es un array de objetos. filter() devolvería todos los objetos del array tales que tengan una propiedad, `display_name`, con valor `"user_ds"`. Devuelve los objetos completos, no solo esa propiedad, por eso luego los puedes usar en el forEach().

Comment: Entiendo. Ahora lo que me pasa es que yo necesito obtener cada object singular (despues del DATA, como arriba.. y mostrar los datos de esos solamente si se cumple la funcion de true o false (ya que, los objects cambian segun si el streamer esta En vivo o OFF)

Comment: Tras aplicar filter() ya tienes el array filtrado. Para "mostrar los datos" ya depende de cómo lo quieras hacer. Puedes incluir la lógica dentro del forEach(), que usa solo los datos filtrados, puedes guardar `datos.data.filter(...)` en otra variable ... Depende de tu caso particular.